# Spanish to English dictionary on Mac's dictionary app?

Tags: macos, dictionary

Is there a way to add Spanish to English dictionary in mac's dictionary app so I can see the definition of word by tapping on a word?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple has introduced Spanish to English dictionary in Yosemite.

You can enable the dictionary named "Gran Diccionario Oxford - Español-Inglés • Inglés-Español" by going to Preferences of Dictionary app.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to search the internet for one that someone has made.  Some others can be found at

http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2013/01/adding-dictionaries-to-dictionaryapp.html

Let me know if you find Spanish-English so I can add it to the list.